# Flutter. Multiple heroes share same tag. ListView with buttons

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, gesturedetector

Can't figure it out how to solve this problem. So, here is the simplest code which represents my problem:

```
   Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...
          Scrollbar(
            child: ListView.builder(
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _mapBloc?.mapData?.companies?.count ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final company = _mapBloc?.mapData?.companies?.data[index];
                return InkWell(
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: company.id,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushNamed('/company', arguments: company)
                        .then(
                      (results) {
                        if (results is PopWithResults) {
                          PopWithResults popResult = results;
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

And stack trace:

```
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must
have a unique non-null tag.
...
```

The items count in ListView changes with every database request. If the size is up to 5 widgets in ListView, then clicking works correctly, as soon as the list expands to, for example, 8 elements, I get the error written above. With what it can be connected? I tried to use unique Hero tags, but this does not solve the problem.

I need some advice and hope you can help me. If you need more information, please, write the comment.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Do you have multiple companies that have the same `id`? `tag: company.id,` must be unique so there must not be any two companies that have the same `id` in your list. This is a requirement from the Hero widget. And note, it must not only be unique in this specific ListView, but in the whole current Screen (probably your Scaffold). Do you use another Hero widget anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The solution was in another Hero widget without a tag that I just forgot about.